# Indy TCP communications and line breaks

Tags: delphi, encryption, indy

I have an error that is confusing the hell out of me. The following code sends a line from a TidTCPClient to a TidTCPServer. The first time it executes, it works perfectly. The second time it executes, and every time after that, it adds a line break to the start of every string. What am I missing? (I know it does it in an odd way, but the list of clients is necessary in the full code)

```
   procedure TClientForm.ButtonSendStringClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      I: integer;
      List: TList;
    begin
      List := ClientList.LockList;
      try
       for I := 0 to (List.Count- 1) do
        begin
          TidTCPClient(List[I]).IOHandler.WriteLn('Hello'+'|x|');
        end;
      finally
       ClientList.UnlockList;
      end;
      Edit1.Text := '';
    end;

    procedure TClientForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    var
    LLine: string;
    begin
    LLine := Acontext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn('|x|');
    OutputDebugString(PChar(LLine));
    end;
```

Comment: May I ask you why you are using a threadsafe list in the sender code? that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: An unknown number (at compile time) of client instances are created earlier and this sends a string to each, hence the Clientlist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WriteLn()` appends a CRLF to the end of the string you pass to it, but `ReadLn()` stops reading when it encounters the terminator string that you specify.  So you are sending `'Hello|x|#13#10'` but you are only reading `'Hello|x|'`, leaving `#13#10` in the socket buffer for the next read to grab.

To solve your problem, you have two choices:

1) If you want to keep using a custom terminator in `ReadLn()`, change `WriteLn()` to `Write()` so the implicit CRLF is not sent anymore. No change is needed in your `ReadLn()` call.

```
Write('Hello|x|');
LLine := ReadLn('|x|');
```

2) Stop using a custom terminator altogether. Pass just your main string by itself to `WriteLn()` and let it append a CRLF, then do not pass any terminator  to `ReadLn()` as its default terminator is LF (which includes handling for CRLF).

```
WriteLn('Hello');
LLine := ReadLn();
```

Answer (score 2):

I see a potential problem in your client code, `ClientList.unlocklist` should be executed outside your loop:

```
procedure TClientForm.ButtonSendStringClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
  List      : TList; 
begin     
  List := ClientList.LockList;
  try
   for I := 0 to (List.Count- 1) do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Text to encrypt is ' + Edit1.Text);
      TidTCPClient(List[I]).IOHandler.WriteLn((Encrypt(Edit1.Text,'Pass')+'|x|'));      
    end;
  finally
   ClientList.UnlockList;
  end;
  Edit1.Text := '';
end;
```

Do not use showmessage in the execute event of your server, since this is not the main GUI thread you must use `synchronize` or use another logging method.
An other potential problem is the fact that your encrypted string may contain carriage return characters or even null characters (#0) in those cases the `Readln` method of your server will be unable to read the entire encrypted string and so fail to decrypt.
One way to resolve this is to use `base64 encoding`.

**EDIT**

The problem lies in the fact that you are using the '|x|' terminator in combination with ReadLn. Since you are using writeln from the client side you can do this

```
procedure TClientForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
 LLine: string;
begin
 LLine := Acontext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
 OutputDebugString(PChar(LLine));
end;
```

If you want to use a terminator don't use `writeln` and `readln`

Comment: Having said which, I'll edit the Q to include your better code :) Thanks.

Comment: Ah, is it poor form to use ShowMessage() in different threads?

Comment: Indeed, everything that relates to the GUI must pass via the main thread

Comment: Nope, that's still not it. I edited the Q again to include your code though, and thank you for letting me know about when/when not to use ShowMessage()

Comment: Oh, and Base64 encoding/decoding is included in the encrypt/decrypt functions and works.

Comment: Ah, I've made progress. Doing a test with the same code just sending plaintext, the first send is as expected. All the ones after that are preceded with a newline. Unfortunately I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Should I put it here or on pastebin (or similar)